# Code does work in terminal but not in Crontab

Tags: cron

I'm no expert but have found a solution to send my data from the solarboiler (MK2) to domoticz.
But when i paste the code in crontab only step 1 will execute.

Step 1

```
0/1* * * * *   wget -O /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/current_packets.vbus http://192.168.2.131/current/current_packets.vbus
```

The file is downloaded from the solar boiler (MK2) and is placed in a local directory.

Step 2

```
0/1* * * * *   cd /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/; /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/formatter -- simple-json /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/current_packets.vbus
```

The file is converted to a JSON file.

Step 3

```
0/1* * * * *   sshpass -p "mastermind" scp -v /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/Output.json  sander@192.168.2.177:/home/sander/zonneboiler
```

The code is transferred to my domoticz machine in the correct directory.

Al these lines work properly in the terminal, but in `sudo crontab -e` only step 1 works.

Does someone has any experience with this issue?

Comment: Did you try without sudo? It is possible that root has no permissions where your regular user has access: So try with your user's crontab: `crontab -e` and put the command lines there. Particularly ssh, step 3, should not be run with sudo (as root). It is also possible that the limited environment of cron is causing the problem: be sure that PATH and other environment variables are either worked around or supplied where necessary.

Comment: Use absolute paths in cron.  3 times 0/1 ? How can you assure these are execute in the order you want? (if the wget takes 10 seconds ... the other 2 are already done) Please put these lines in a SCRIPT and use that in crontab. You can execute the script on command line and add debugging so you can easily detect problems when using cron . and use `/etc/cronab` you can add a user to your line that is used to execute it

Answer (score 2):

Create a "script" in `/home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/`. Add ...

```
cd /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/
/usr/bin/wget -O current_packets.vbus http://192.168.2.131/current/current_packets.vbus
./formatter -- simple-json current_packets.vbus
/usr/bin/sshpass -p "mastermind" scp -v Output.json sander@192.168.2.177:/home/sander/zonneboiler
```

(I assumed `/usr/bin/` for both) You can start the script manually to test if it works. Then ...

Do `sudo vi /etc/crontab` and add

```
0/1 * * * *  pi  cd /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/ && ./script >>/home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/cron.log 2>&1
```

Then test this setup.

- ssh proably needs your `pi` user so that is why to use /etc/crontan and not crontab
- If this does not work from cron this file will hold the errors and all other text that would be show in the terminal:

  ```
  /home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter/cron.log 2>&1
  ```

Comment: Thx for all the solutions. Will try and feedback the result

Comment: @sanderj unless you are already familiar with `vi`, you probably want `sudo nano /etc/crontab` instead of `sudo vi /etc/crontab`.  .

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can rely on those 3 cron entries to execute sequentially.  They could be trying to run at the same time causing all sorts of problems.  You could combine them into one long command line in one cron entry.  But since that will be getting a bit long, a better way would be to put all your commands in a script and just run that script from your cronfile.

Lets say you create a file called $HOME/bin/myformatter (with the text editor of your choice).  (You might need to `mkdir -p $HOME/bin` first) Then put the following in it

```
#!/bin/bash
fdir=/home/pi/resol-vbus.rs/examples/formatter
vbus=$fdir/current_packets.vbus
wget -O $vbus http://192.168.2.131/current/current_packets.vbus
cd $fdir
$fdir/formatter -- simple-json $vbus
sshpass -p "mastermind" scp -v $fdir/Output.json sander@192.168.2.177:/home/sander/zonneboiler
```

make it executable (`chmod +x $HOME/bin/myformatter`) then create a cron entry like

0/1 * * * * $HOME/bin/myformatter

And like @sudodus said, if you are not running the original command via sudo, don't run crontab with sudo either.

crontab -e edits your crontab.  sudo crontab -e edits root's crontab.  If you switch to your crontab, be sure to remove the entries from root's so they are not both running.

p.s. since it looks like you may have included a password in your post, please change that right away.

Comment: Password is already changed. Thx for al the feedback. When im back from holiday i will check the solutions